# Save arrays strategy in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, performance, file, memory

I came to this issues recently where I have to decide if I save a list of arrays all in one file or keep it in separeted files.

Here's the deal. I have an array of arrays, I'll simplify the example:

```
countries['america'] = array('chile', 'brazil', 'usa');
countries['europe'] = array('france', 'italy', 'spain');
...and so.
```

So, I could save all the arrays in one big file (name it 'world'), and whenever I'll have to query a country in a continent I'll load all the file in memory.

Or, I could save each array in a different file (name it 'america', 'europe', etc), and whenever I'll have to query a country in a continent I'll load the corresponding file.

I know it all comes to sizes, so imagine the world has 10 continents and each continent has 2000 countries.

What is the best approach?

Note: this is a performance issue and I prefer to avoid calling a database.

Comment: you can [serialize](http://php.net/serialize) the array, but you'd definitely be better off using a database

Comment: This is a performance issue so I'm trying to avoid calling the database.

Comment: @cgajardo reading details on up to 20000 countries from disk on every request will be more of a performance issue.

Comment: @Sammitch I was trusting php to keep recurrent data in memory.

Comment: So you were planning to store it in a persistent in-memory cache of some sort, such as [APC](http://php.net/apc)?

Comment: @cgajardo PHP does not keep anything in memory between requests that isn't stored in $_SESSION, and $_SESSION is still written to disk. PHP also does not share any data between simultaneous requests. So if you have 1000 users all making a request that requires a file to be read into memory, then that file will be read 1000 times. A database will cache recent query results in memory and serve them much faster.

Comment: @sammitch you are right. I'm a newbie to PHP and don't know much really. I'll give [mongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org) a try and I'll run it in the same server as PHP to avoid remote calling. 

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can store the array into in-memory cache system, like xcache or memcached. This way your data will be kept into the ram and it will be far more speedy and lightweight than database or file-based storage.

See [xcache](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/) and [memcached](http://memcached.org/)